# Error! conflicting action statements: project_path, state (ansible)

Tags: ansible

Trying to execute this code but having the said errors encountered above

code

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   collections:
    - community.general.terraform
   tasks:
   - name: Execute Terraform Template
     project_path: '/Users/<username>/Desktop/<repository>/<file>'
     state: present
     force_init: true
```

```
The offending line appears to be:

   tasks:
   - name: Execute Terraform Template
     ^ here
```

been trying to figure this one out.. I am using a macOS, installed Ansible locally already.

Thank you in advance!!

Trying to execute the code above but unable to succeed.

Comment: In YAML indentation **do** matter. Have a look at the indentation in the [documentation examples for this module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/terraform_module.html#examples).

Comment: Please take [y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/), install a [yaml linter](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and systematically verify your files before posting.

Comment: Even a valid yaml can be an invalid ansible file, Use [`ansible-lint`](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation problem in your script.

Should work like this:

```
- name: Run Terraform
  gather_facts: No
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Execute Terraform Template
      terraform:
        project_path: '/Users/<username>/Desktop/<repository>/<file>'
        state: present
        force_init: true
```

Comment: I am also getting this:
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
localhost does not match 'all'

Comment: That is correct. At your script you are only using `hots: localhost`. What's the issue?

Comment: Still encountering the mentioned issue above even though I have already applied your corrections with my indention on the script.

Comment: Are you still having an ERROR or just the WARNING?

Comment: Still having the same error mentioned above.

Comment: Can you please copy my code and try again? If the error persists please place it here.

Comment: ERROR! conflicting action statements: project_path, state

The error appears to be in '/Users/michaeytenorio/Desktop/github-exercise-4/mkt.yaml': line 7, column 8, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

   tasks:
     - name: Execute Terraform Template
       ^ here


This is the error that I am getting when executing the ansible-playbook command

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are related to typos. Vote to close them if you have that right, leave a comment to guide people on how to check their examples prior to posting their questions. Moreover, your above example is invalid so even more misleading as there is no module name in your task and options are still not using the right indentation.

Comment: Sorry @Zeitounator. I thought that help someone that have doubts was better. Michaey please look at my answer now. It's sorted.

Comment: @MichaeyTenorio is it solved?

Comment: You can help people by writing comments even if their questions do not reach the quality threshold. Question related to typos are not helpful for others as they will most likely never be read again (hence why it is a close reason). `Error! conflicting action statements` is a clear error message for which you will finds existing examples and solutions on this site or in your favorite search engine. Note that your edit is still not good as the indentation is not consistent throughout the file (1 or 2 spaces depending on the places in your file) which can lead to potential errors/confusion.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for the tips. Edited again.

Comment: It was worse. Edited. My opinion is that this answer should be deleted and the question closed because caused by a typo.

Comment: Hi @NunoOliveira my issue is now resolve! thank you so much for the help!! will have this studied as well. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for the tips as well sir!

Comment: Hey @MichaeyTenorio since it’s resolved can you bump my answer and mark as solution? It will help on my reputation